# Check how many "," in each line in Perl

Tags: perl, file, line

I have to check how many times was "," in each line in file. Anybody have idea how can I do it in Perl?

On this moment my code looks like it:

```
open($list, "<", $student_list)
while ($linelist = <$list>)
{
   printf("$linelist");
}
close($list)
```

But I have no idea how to check how many times is "," in each $linelist :/

Comment: Also use semicolons `;` at 1st and last line in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr) in counting mode:

```
my $commas = $linelist =~ y/,//;
```

Answer (score 3):

Edited in your code :

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $list, "<", "file.csv" or die $!;
while (my $linelist = <$list>)
{
    my $commas = $linelist =~ y/,//;
    print "$commas\n";
}
close($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count the number of somethings in a file, you don't need to read it into memory. Since you aren't changing the file, mmap would be just fine:

```
use File::Map qw(map_file);
map_file my $map, $filename, '<';
my $count = $map =~ tr/,//;
```

Comment: Your code is reading file into memory as well. Your remark about memory is misleading.

Comment: It's a different sort of memory that the Perl process can discard when it's done with it.

Comment: Perl process can't discard it, kernel does. Anyway, sentence _you don't need to read it into memory_ is simply misleading. In your code, it is read whole into memory and is up to kernel if some pages of virtual memory behind `$map` is freed. You are making false impression that the part of the file will no be read into memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! perl
# perl script.pl [file path]
use strict;
use warnings;
my $file = shift or die "No file name provided";
open(my $IN, "<", $file) or die "Couldn't open file $file: $!";
my @matches = ();
my $index = 0;
# while <$IN> will get the file one line at a time rather than loading it all into memory
while(<$IN>){
  my $line = $_;
  my $current_count = 0;
  # match globally, meaning keep track of where the last match was
  $current_count++ while($line =~ m/,/g);
  $matches[$index] = $current_count;
  $index++;
}

$index = 0;
for(@matches){
  $index++;
  print "line $index had $_ matches\n" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mmap` Perl IO layer instead of [File::Map](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Map). It is almost as efficient as former but most probably present in your Perl installation without needing installing a module. Next, using `y///` is more efficient than `m//g` in array context.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant STUDENT_LIST => 'text.txt';

open my $list, '<:mmap', STUDENT_LIST;

while ( my $line = <$list> ) {
    my $count = $line =~ y/,//;
    print "There is $count commas at $.. line.\n";
}
```

If you would like grammatically correct output you can use [Lingua::EN::Inflect](http://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Inflect) in the right place

```
use Lingua::EN::Inflect qw(inflect);
print inflect "There PL_V(is,$count) $count PL_N(comma,$count) at ORD($.) line.\n";
```

Example output:

```
There are 7 commas at 1st line.
There are 0 commas at 2nd line.
There is 1 comma at 3rd line.
There are 2 commas at 4th line.
There are 7 commas at 5th line.
```

Comment: `print Linuga::EN::Inflect::inflect "There PL_V(is,$commas) $commas PL_N(comma,$commas) at $.. line.\n"`

Answer (score -1):

Do you want #commas for each line in the file, or #commas in the entire file?

On a per-line basis, replace your while loop with:

```
my @data = <list>;
foreach my $line {
  my @chars = split //, $line;
  my $count = 0;
  foreach my $c (@chars) { $count++ if $c eq "," }
  print "There were $c commas\n";
}
```